# Clone Commerce Product Option Sets

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

This issue hints it's possible to clone Option sets https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_option/issues/1319618

> To reproduce:
>
> On page admin/commerce/products/option-sets Click 'clone' on any
>   product option set. New option set appears as [original option set
>   name] (cloned) Selecting 'Manage Fields' shows no fields and selecting
>   'Manage Display' shows no fields added.

But there is no Clone button anywhere to be found under `admin/commerce/products/option-sets` following that instruction.

Does it require any additional module?

Answer (score 1):

Commerce Product Option is an unsupported module. You should not be using it. If you want similar functionality with core support (e.g. options on an Add to Cart form that aren't required to correspond to unique SKUs), use custom line item types with line item fields instead.